# When do clerics gain the ability to learn 4th-level spells or higher? How does spell level increase?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

I am new at being a spell caster. I am a 6th-level cleric and I know 1st-3rd level spells. When do I learn higher spells? Does spell level increase when my character level increases?

Comment: Hello, Maia.  Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get an idea of how an SE Q&A site works.  The likely reason for the down votes on this question is a lack of basic research.  The SE model works best when some basic research is done before asking a question.  The free basic rules have a lot of good basic information, and [are free to download here](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf#page=21).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Cleric table in the PHB (pg. 57) shows the spell level progression. You gain access to 4th level spells when you  reach level 7, since you do not have any 4th level spell slots available at any level before then. So yes, you learn higher level spells as you gain levels in cleric.

Clerics know all of their spells for every spell level they have spell slots for. You can prepare any spells that are of a higher level at the end of a long rest, as you would have been doing for the 1st-3rd level spells you currently use.